# Sending and Receiving Data with Sockets in android

Tags: android, client, serversocket

I need to create server and client android apps, I used this [code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android) , they connected but can't send/receive data.

please your advice.

[image]

Comment: You should enter a message and press the SEND button!

Comment: In both Thread3 classes change `output.write(message);` to `output.write(message + "\n");`. You should send a line as both receivers try to read a line with readLine().

Comment: But sometimes the client send message to the server but the server doesn't receive it.. can you guess why?

Comment: Did you find solution @Tarek